# How to load React jsx with jquery load?

Tags: jquery, ajax, reactjs

I have one file (master) that calls another file (loaded) with [jquery .load().](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

In loaded file, javascrips works, but jsx code gets ignored.

Is it possible to load jsx code this way? If it is, how?

If not, what alternatives we have - how to process jsx code in loaded files?

Code of master page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>React</title>
    <script src="https://fb.me/react-with-addons-0.13.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#loaded").load("loaded.html", function(responseText, textStatus, req) {});
      });
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>

  <p>Master page</p>

  <div id="loaded"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Code of loaded page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log("JQUERY WORKS");
</script>

<script type="text/jsx">
  console.log("REACT WORKS");
</script>


<p>loaded page</p>
```

Edit: What am I trying to accomplish: I'm working on a web app, that loads its "page fragments" with jquery load, and I need to render a React component inside that fragment.

Comment: Why would you even consider injecting JSX "code" into a container? Are you trying to render a React component inside a container? Also, the code example you provided is not JSX.

Comment: @David exactly, I'm trying to render a React component inside a container, that is loaded with jquery load. I'v edited the original question. Can console.log("REACT WORKS"); in jsx be any problem?

Comment: You should precompile the JSX files and just use `React.render` with a specific target element (which you could select via jQuery if you'd like). Compiling them on the fly will perform poorly and result in unnecessary "busy work" on the client.

Comment: @WiredPrairie that seems like a solution, my workflow  was probably just plain wrong (thought I'll compile all on deploy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a workflow doesn't seem right with React. Better approach is (for example) :

- install react tools

  npm install -g react-tools
- develop components in .jsx files in (for example) jsx folder
- compile jsx automatically if is edited to .js files to (for example) js folder with console command

  jsx --extension jsx  --watch   jsx/    js/
- use .js files in web app

Comment: Yes, this is a far better solution for React.

Comment: you could want to load an heavy component on some conditions only

Answer (score 1):

You have to separate the JS/jQuery logic from the React's one

I would advise you to build a non-React program on the top of your application in order to manage your fragments

Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44804330/5040294) first sentences about fetching and **eval**uating dynamicaly loaded script **and** about inserting `<script>` tags pointing to a self-running component (see after, solution 2)

---

**Solution 1 :**

```
// index.js
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

$(() => {
  window.components = {}

  window.loadComponent = componentKey =>
    fetch(`/components/${ componentKey }`)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(text => {
        window.components[componentKey] = eval(text)
        render(window.components[componentKey],
          document.getElementById(`anchor-${ componentKey }`))
})
```

A better approach would **use a Redux approach to ensure both the single source of truth and one-way data workflow** principles

---

**Solution 2**
Here we encapsulate our component with a simple rendering logic

The component can now be linked in your DOM with a `<script>` tag

```
// fragment-bundle.js
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import Fragment from './Fragment/Fragment'

render(<Fragment/>, document.getElementById('anchor-fragment'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do here, but the JSX transformer comes with a transform method, so you could try something like:

```
$.get('loaded.html', function(jsx) {
    var transformed = JSX.transform(jsx);
    $('#loaded').html('<script>'+transformed.code+'</script>');
})
```

Comment: How do I get reference to JSX?