# Using $timeout to load a second version of jQuery in Angular.js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, timeout

let's assume I need to load multiple versions of jQuery in my Angular.js app.

After some test I understood that when I try to load a particular view with the 2nd version of jQuery inside it, my app uses only the first one, so I saw there is a sort of "hack" with `$timeout`, but I'm still not able to reproduce it.

My view code is basically this (consider that in index is previously loaded a 2.1.4 version of jQuery):

```
<script src="http://somepath/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
console.log( "2nd loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery );
jq311 = jQuery.noConflict( true );
console.log( "After $.noConflict(true)" );
console.log( "1st loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery);
console.log( "2nd loaded jQuery version (jq311): " + jq311.fn.jquery );
</script>
```

And my JavaScript is like that:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event) {
                      $timeout(function() {
                          jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
                                alert("now loading jQuery");
                                console.log( " loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery );
                            });
                      },0);
                });
```

When alert comes, in the console the following code is shown:

```
loaded jQuery version ($): 2.1.4
```

I know I'm messing something in the JavaScript, but I can't figure out what.
Any hint?

UPDATE:
I now achieved the loading of the 2nd jQuery using [ocLazyLoad][1]

```
console.log( "1st loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery );
                $ocLazyLoad.load('somepath/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js').then(function(response) {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        console.log( "2nd loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery );
                        var jq311 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
                        console.log( "After jQuery.noConflict(true)" );
                        console.log( "1st loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery);
                        console.log( "2nd loaded jQuery version (jq311): " + jq311.fn.jquery );
                     },0);
                });
```

but I'm still not able to use `noConflict` method

Here the console output:

```
1st loaded jQuery version ($): 2.1.4
2nd loaded jQuery version ($): 3.1.1
After jQuery.noConflict(true)
1st loaded jQuery version ($): 3.1.1
2nd loaded jQuery version (jq311): 3.1.1
```

Any hint why I'm not able to choose jQuery?
[1]: https://oclazyload.readme.io/

Comment: Why would you load multiple versions of jQuery?

Comment: i need to run multiple version cause i need to add some new functionality on a big project without touching previous code

Comment: Script loading is not handled by viewContentLoaded. It's not supported by Angular at all. Actually, <script> in templates is a hack itself, you're able to use it because of jQuery. Generally you should load the script programmatically [like that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44807594/3731501). If this won't work for you, consider providing http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem.