# Using `dynamic import` to fetch script from another host?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I run my next.js app on `localhost:3001`. I want to fetch script from another host (`localhost:3000`). I could do it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44803944/can-i-run-a-js-script-from-another-using-fetch). As for me, much prettier would be using `dynamic import`. But I got an error: 'ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http://localhost:3000/static/fileToFetch.js' in '/Users/{username}/Desktop/test-project/pages';

Example:

```
export const FetchedComponent = dynamic({
  loader: () =>
    import('http://localhost:3000/static/fileToFetch.js'),
  loading: () => 'Loading...',
  ssr: false,
});
```

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: The easiest way to load external files would be to `fetch` it.

Comment: I found this doc maybe useful to you https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputcrossoriginloading

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dynamic import with **webpack** is works only for code splitting.
you need to find out how to tell to webpack not to change the `import()` and then enable CORS in that domain.

An alternative way would be to write a function that will inject script tag to the body and return a promise, something like that:

```
function importExternal(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    script.async = true;
    script.onload = () => resolve(window['external_global_component']);
    script.onerror = reject;

    document.body.appendChild(script);
  });
}
```

When the file that you are loading, putting on the global (`external_global_component`) the component that was loaded.
And then, you will able to use it with NextJS `dynamic`.

```
export const FetchedComponent = dynamic({
  loader: () =>
    importExternal('http://localhost:3000/static/fileToFetch.js'),
  loading: () => 'Loading...',
  ssr: false, // <- must be false, because we are using DOM.
});
```